# Scala apache/zeppelin:0.7.3: import does not work

Tags: scala, apache-zeppelin

I try to prototype UDAF in a Zeppelin notebook running in an official Docker container

```
%spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction

class MyClass() extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {}
```

and get following error:

*error: not found: type UserDefinedAggregateFunction
       class MyClass() extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {}*

when I run:

```
class MyClass() extends org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction {}
```

it works.
I think, its related to issue described here

https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg59520.html,

but have no idea for a workaround, except for typing full paths.

Any ideas?

Regards
Paweł